# validação de formulario na mesma página

Tags: php

Olá, para que o formulário seja validado na mesma página, o que é mais seguro como valor para o atributo 'action' html? Obrigado.

```
    <form method="post" action="">
    <!--ou-->
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
```

Comment: O action é um URL. Tem de ser um valor válido para URL, um destino que o servidor aceite. Não percebo porque usar `htmlspecialchars()` ou porque pensar que ele não é seguro.

Comment: Sugiro que você pesquise sobre Jquery + ajax, alem de fazer a mesma coisa, é mais elegante ao usuario, e não precisa dar refresh na pagina;

Comment: Olá nilson, não está claro qual é sua dúvida. Passando a URL pelo htmlspecialchars o que você está tentando fazer?

Comment: O objetivo é que as mensagens de erro, ou de sucesso de envio, permaneçam na mesma página. Mas, parece que devo pesquisar melhor, para evitar o refresh na página, como foi sugerido. Obrigado.

Comment: @Nilson veja esse exemplo basico de uso. http://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/514131-envio-de-formulario-com-ajax/

Comment: Opá, vou estudar sim esse exemplo, obrigado. Uma dúvida, nesse caso, o script php que valida o formulário, não precisa ficar na mesma página do formulário? Minha duvida começou ao tentar fazer isso da forma com descrito no exemplo baseado em estudos feitos aqui http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_validation.asp e descobrir que usando htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]) evitaria a manipulação da url por terceiros, já que o valor atribuído a action, nesse caso, viria da url atual. E depois, pesquisando mais, achei esta outra forma: action="", que disseram ser mais segura. Blz, vou estudar +

Comment: @Nilson não há como evitar manipulação de absolutamente nada que venha do lado do usuário. A aplicação (lado do servidor) tem que estar sempre preparada para isso.

Comment: @Nilson não precisa ser a mesma página no action. Não precisa nem ter action no form, dependendo de como tu vai fazer a requisição ajax.

Comment: @RafaelMenaBarreto, vou estudar ajax. Eu queria um norte e consegui com a ajuda de vcs, obrigado.

Answer (score 4):

**1º** Não inventa.

**2º** Não é uma questão de qual é melhor, deves saber o que faz cada um.

`htmlentities` codifica qualquer caractere especial, de modo que não seja possível injectar tags ou algum js.

Deixar o atributo `action` vazio, faz com que essa página referencie a si mesma. Por isso não desperdices funções usando-as onde não são necessárias, porque o que o `PHP_SELF` faz, é retornar o nome do ficheiro que está a executar o script, por isso, se não há `QUERY_STRING` porquê devo eu utilizar o `htmlentities` ou `urlencode` ? Simplesmente não deves, porque a principal razão para usa-las, é retornar estes valores no formato certo, para que possam ser usadas sem problemas, isso **caso** existirem.

Um exemplo disto é:

```
<?php
    echo '<a href="' . htmlspecialchars("/nextpage.php?stage=23&data=" .
        urlencode($data)) . '">'."\n";
?>
```

A `url` contém parâmetros, logo possui caracteres especiais que precisam de ser escapados, mas o que faz o `urlencode` aí ? Simplesmente faz o que faz, quando ser quer passar o valor de uma variável como parte de uma `url`, é aí que se torna útil.

Eu diria o que muita gente diz normalmente em situações como esta, **usa** uma biblioteca js qualquer, ou usa simplesmente o js, **e o teu problema desaparece**.

Seria fácil pensar assim, devido ao avanço tecnológico até os sites mais simples utilizam javascript, sendo que grande parte dos dispositivos atualmente usados para acessar estes sites possuem também suporte ao javascript. Mas é o que é, javascript pode falhar, uma ou outra vez, e há vezes em que simplesmente alguns preferem não usar, mas isso já é outra perspectiva.

Analisa melhor as tuas prioridades, e procure uma solução que se adeque a ti.

Se quiseres ler mais sobre sobre alguns destes processos, eis algumas páginas que recomendo:

- [Dealing with Forms](http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php)
- [PHP and HTML](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php)

Comment: Obrigado pela sugestão, vou continuar estudando, e quando estiver mais bem preparado, retorna aqui.

Comment: Experimenta trabalhar com exemplos práticos, é melhor forma entender o comportamento destas funções e atributos.

Answer (score 1):

Qualquer valor. A *action* não influencia em validação por parte de cliente. A validação em página normalmente é feita em JS, e o PHP tem pouco papel nisso.

Neste caso, uma ótima opção é o [jQuery Validation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/). [Veja funcionando aqui](http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/).